# Can't upload files via FTP on Mac OS

Tags: macos, ftp, upload, filezilla, panic-transmit

I can access, read and download from host via FTP, but can't upload files.

I tied to use Transmit (on Mac) and Filezilla also, but no success.

Then tried same on a different host and got the same problem.

> Could not upload "logo.png".
>   Server said:
>   Error - 132: could not send file to remote host

[image: could not send dialog error]

I tried also PASSIVE mode on FTP client, and vice-versa, but again nothing.

The issue is only on the Mac-based FTP client as I am still able to connect using CuteFTP or Filezilla or other FTP clients on Windows.

Comment: I know this is probably the first thing you checked.. but your username/password for the FTP Server have Write Access?
Oh, and have enough space left for you to upload more files?

Comment: Yes I checked this all, but everything is ok. It's working in windows CuteFTP or Filezilla or other FTP clients.
I got problem only on Mac based FTP clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time searching of solution finally found a solution.

Problem is caused by macs MTU settings:

<kbd>Settings</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Network</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Advanced</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>Hardware</kbd>

Put: <kbd>MTU:</kbd><kbd>1400</kbd>

Finally FTP transfer is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the account you’re using doesn’t have Write access to the server, you need to confirm that with the server admin.

Comment: Account has write access because, when I use it with Windows based FTP clients, it's working properly.
I get error on Mac based FTP clients.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading is not supported by macOS (or OSX) for quite some time through Finder, according to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119519/built-in-ftp-client-cmd-k-cant-upload-files-mavericks) post. Since the command line utilities for `ftp` is removed altogether, Finder may not be able to call those. However, try [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/), both of which are Free Software (free as in freedom, though also free as in free beer).

Comment: That only affects FTP storage mounted in the Finder. It doesn't apply to standalone FTP clients, like Transmit and Filezilla (which the OP mentioned using).

Comment: @duskwuff As I said, it is possible with 3rd parties, but not possible through Finder via Command+K. I see no reason to downvote.